# Expression body should be of type 'MethodCallExpression'

Tags: c#, delegates, hangfire

I have a function -

```
public async Task DoWork(Frequency value) { // do work }
```

The idea here is to add this function as a recurring job to Hangfire.

Adding the job explicitly works, like this -

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("triggerId", () => DoWork(frequency), Cron.Daily())
```

However, if I want to create a function to add triggers

```
private void AddTrigger(string triggerId, Frequency frequency, Func<Frequency, Task> trigger)
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(triggerId, () => trigger(frequency), Cron.Daily());
}
```

I get an error `Expression body should be of type 'MethodCallExpression'`

When I debug it seems like they are the same type of objects. What am I missing here that is causing this error?

```
() => trigger(frequency)    {Method = {System.Threading.Tasks.Task <<>m0>b__0()}}   object {System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>}
() => DoWork(frequency)     {Method = {System.Threading.Tasks.Task <<>m0>b__0()}}   object {System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate` overload you're calling accepts an `Expression<Func<Task>>`. That's an *expression tree* representing a call that returns a task.

Unfortunately, `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate` requires that expression tree to represent a method call - it calls `Job.FromExpression`, which eventually ends up in [this code](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/f87fd22e3661e05eb039fe45cb1aafb5b4c688b5/src/Hangfire.Core/Common/Job.cs#L321). Every `Job` is eventually built from a `MethodInfo`. Your lambda expression is an invocation via a parameter, so it doesn't work.

You could wrap the invocation in a method call, as below - I don't know if it will actually work though... you may find that you end up with a lot of jobs with a name of "Execute".

```
private void AddTrigger(string triggerId, Frequency frequency, 
                        Func<Frequency, Task> trigger)
{
    var wrapper = new TriggerWrapper(() => trigger(frequency));
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(triggerId, () => wrapper.Execute(), Cron.Daily());
}

private class TriggerWrapper
{
    private Func<Task> func;

    internal TriggerWrapper(Func<Task> func) => this.func = func;

    public Task Execute() => func();
}
```

Comment: I see so this seems to be a limitation by Hangfire since an invocation doesn't have the same properties. Currently I am getting the delegate by using a string key with a switch statement. Thinking maybe I just do that afterwards and have a generic `ExecuteTrigger` function

Comment: @Adjit: It's definitely a Hangfire limitation, yes - if you follow the link in my answer, you'll see the code which makes the check. You could potentially file a feature request...

Comment: I follow your code and got this message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at "public Task Execute() => func();". Can you help?

Comment: @GinCanhViet: Please create a new question with a [mcve].